# How to install Polymer 2.0 elements?

Tags: polymer, bower

Because the Polymer-2.0 is in preview stage, it is not in main branch. I am looking for installation procedure for Polymer-2.0 elements.

I would use `bower install iron-pages` to install the Polymer 1.x component. So what should I do with the 2.0 components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the `2.0-preview` components:

```
bower install iron-pages#2.0-preview
```